# Map float values(0.0, 100.0) into RGB

Tags: c++, c, math, graphics, colors

I have around 1000 float values in the range(0.0, 100.0) and I want to map these values into a color(RGB). What I did so far is to create a colormap with 1000 color(RGB) values, use the float values to index the colormap and get an RGB value.

But the problem is, I'm loosing precision since I cast float values into int before using them as indices to my colormap.  What is the best way to do this float to rgb conversion?

EDIT:

```
color color_list[100];
float float_values[1000]
for(i = 0 to 999)
{
   int colormap_idx = float_values[i];  // Note that the float is converted into an int
   color current_color = color_list[colormap_idx];
}
```

Comment: we can't tell you how to improve your code if you don't show the code ;)

Comment: Since you give us so many information about how the color mapping should be done, I'm gonna go for greyscale... `R = G = B = value * 255 / 100` (hint: there is a question hidden in my jest)

Comment: Sounds like a map<float, tRGB>?

Comment: thanks for the replies, I added more info

Comment: Use a smarter conversion.

Comment: Sounds like your color_list it's just 1d texture without map levels. Maybe look at sampling and filtering textures algorithms (linear interpolation between nearest points in your case most easy).

Comment: Why would `color current_color = roundf(255 * float_values[i]);` not suffice? Is there something special about how you initialize `color_list`? Also, why do you use `int colormap_idx = float_values[i];` rather than `int colormap_idx = roundf(float_values[i]);`?

Comment: @user1837009, Yes it is a 1-D texture, with a RGB value per line.  Can you please point me to what kind of filtering/sampling techniques you are talking about?

Comment: @user933322: what @user1837009 means is: get r,g,b levels for both the current `floor` and `ceil` floating point number. Get the fractional part of your float number, and use `rd = rf + f*(rc - rf)`, where rd=destination, rf=red(floor(float)), rc=red(ceil(float)) and f is the fractional part. Repeat for green and blue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total number of RGB values you can have is 256^3. It would be nice if you could utilize all of them, but sometimes it can be hard to come up with a nice intuitive mapping. Since there are a total possible of 256^4 floats (more than possible RGB values) you will lose precision no matter what you do, but you can still do much, much better than what you currently.

I don't know exactly what you are doing with the pre-defined color map, but consider defining only a few intermediate colors that correspond to a few intermediate floating values and interpolating each input floating point value. In the code below, fsample and csample are your corresponding points. For example:

```
fsample[0] = 0.0   -> csample[0] = (0, 0, 0)
fsample[1] = 0.25  -> csample[1] = (0, 0, 100)
fsample[2] = 0.5   -> csample[2] = (0, 170, 170)
fsample[3] = 0.75  -> csample[3] = (170, 170, 0)
fsample[4] = 1.0   -> csample[4] = (255, 255, 255)
```

This will allow you to cover a lot more ground in RGB space with floats, allowing a higher precision conversion, while still giving you some power to flexibly define intermediate colors. This is a fairly common method to convert grayscale to color.

There are a few optimizations and error checks you can apply to this code, but I left it unoptimized for the sake of clarity:

```
int N = float_values.size();
color colormap[N];
for(i = 0 to N)
{
    colormap[i] = RGBFromFloat(float_values[i], fsample, csample, num_samples);
}



color RGBFromFloat(float in, float fsample[], float csample[], num_samples)
{
    color out;

    // find the interval that the input 'in' lies in
    // this is a simple search on an ordered array...
    // consider replacing with a better algorithm for a large number of samples
    for(i = 0 to num_samples-1)
    {
        if(fsample[i] =< in && in < fsample[i+1])
        {
             out = interpolate(fsample[i], fsample[i+1], csample[i], csample[i+1], in);    
             break;
        }
    }
    return color;
}

color interpolate(float flow, float fhigh, color clow, color chigh, float in)
{
    float t = (in-flow)/(fhigh-flow);
    return clow*(1 - t) + chigh*t
}
```

Comment: do `fsample[]` values have to normalized ?

Comment: In this example, no, because we are normalizing when computing 't'. However, when using the formula clow*(1-t) + chigh*t, 't' must be normalized.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is ***the best*** method (since you gave us no optimality criteria), but if by "I'm losing precision" you mean that once converted to int, you only have a maximum of 100 different color combinations, then you can do this:

```
// this code is C99

#define MAX_FLOAT_VAL 100.0
#define N_COLORS 2000
#define N_FLOAT_SAMPLES 1000

color color_list[N_COLORS];
float float_values[N_FLOAT_SAMPLES];

// the following loop must be placed in some function
for( int i = 0; i < N_FLOAT_SAMPLES; i++ )
{
    // the following assignment will map 
    // linearly a float in the range [0 ... MAX_FLOAT_VAL]
    // into an int in the range [0 ... (N_COLORS-1)]
    int colormap_idx = (float_values[i] / MAX_FLOAT_VAL) * (N_COLORS - 1);
    color current_color = color_list[colormap_idx];
    // ... do something with current_color ...
}
```

Of course you still have to generate the entries in `color_list` with a suitable algorithm (I advice against doing that by hand :-). This is a whole different problem, since it involves more "degrees of freedom", since you try to map a 1-D space (the values of `colormap_idx`) to a 3-D space (the set of all the possible RGB triples).

P.S: the requirements you seem to have remind me of the computations needed to colorize a fractal like the graphic representation of the Mandelbrot's set.

Hope this helps.